# invoke a function on leaving the current page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I tried to use the **update** function with **onunload**  but the function wasn't invoked. How can invoke the **update** function on leaving or closing the current page? Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function update()
        {
            $.post('http://www.example.com/scripts/home.php');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad design to do stuff `onunload`. You should change your design to something that doesn't rely on this event.

If you must have to, try doing your call in `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: Thanks Mrchief, I think I have to come up with something else since this might cause trouble to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Make in synchronous:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "..." });
```

Users won't like it though. They should be able to close the page whenever they want.

Answer (score 0):

onbeforeunload event should do the trick for you. But the call shuold be synchronous to wait for the response and react to it. With sync call the browser may get hanged which will not be accepted by the user.